# Do I acquire a lock while returning a reference

Tags: java, multithreading

I am going through the source code of cmis API. There one of the method is defined like below.

```
public OperationContext getDefaultContext() {
    lock.readLock().lock();
    try {
        return defaultContext;
    } finally {
        lock.readLock().unlock();
    }
}
```

I would like to know, is it necessary to acquire a lock while returning a reference? if it is required, why should I acquire the lock?

Comment: In this context it looks useless. Maybe they have a method that initializes the `defaultContext` and they are trying to prevent it from being exposed until that method has completed.

Comment: In the end - nice question :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the purposes of a lock is to establish what's known as a happens-before relationship. A computer is allowed to reorder operations, such that what you might intuitively think is "A, then B" might actually look like "A, then B" to one thread, but "B, then A" to another. One of the things synchronization does is to basically tell the computer, "you have to do A, then B."

This can lead to very confusing cases. For instance, you can see what's called a "partial write", where a thread only sees part of some action. Imagine if you set two variables on `defaultContext`: `defaultContext.a = "a"; defaultContext.b = "b";`. Including the return statement, you have three operations: reading `defaultContext` (to return it), and writing *a* and *b*. A thread could see them ordered as `defaultContext.b = "b" ; return defaultContext; defaultContext.a = "a";`. The third of those might come much later, or even never! In other words, that thread will see the write to `defaultContext.b` but not the write to `defaultContext.a`: a partial write.

In this case, A and B are writes and reads to the variable `defaultLock`. If multiple threads are accessing `defaultLock` (even if some one read it, and others only write it), then you need to synchronize, so that each thread has a fully up-to-date of `defaultContext`. You are telling the computer: "those writes to A and B, they really do have to come before the return."

Note that for this to work, you have to set things up a bit carefully, since any subsequent writes to `defaultContext` will not be synchronized. You'd have to have one thread doing all the writes to a local variable (that is, creating and initializing the default context), then write that local variable to `defaultContext` while holding the write lock of `lock`, and then no other thread can modify `defaultContext` after that. In that case, there's an easier way to do it: just make `defaultContext` a `volatile` field, whose writes and reads have a similar happens-before relationship. I can't speculate as to why the author of the code didn't do that.

Assuming the code you're looking at it OpenCMIS's [SessionImpl](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/1.0.1/maven/chemistry-opencmis-client/chemistry-opencmis-client-impl/xref/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/client/runtime/SessionImpl.html#445), this seems to be exactly what's going on. All reads to the defaultContext are done either through the getDefaultContext method you pasted, and all writes happen through a setDefaultContext that uses the writeLock.

Comment: But in this case, this method is just returning the reference. Reference variabel, just refer the memory location. how can it leads the synchronization problems?

Comment: @HariKrishna Updated my answer to address that.

Comment: I agree - nice answer. You deserve the accept and upvotes here.

Answer (score 2):

This simply doesn't make sense - at least when only looking at this one method in isolation.

This code probably serializes the act of fetching that context object. But there is no sense in doing that.

Unless of course there is a corresponding setter which is implemented in a similar fashion. The other answer nicely outlined how such constructs create a order for potential calls that write or read the underlying field.

But thing is: without further explanations, that implicit behavior is very much hidden. Personally, I would prefer a solution that is more explicit. For example by not using the locking approach but by making getter and setter synchronized. Or by at least putting comments into both methods explaining the thoughts behind using that lock.